# Prolog homework help

Tags: list, prolog

Okay, my last prolog question. It's the common geneaology problem.

I am suppose to take a list of facts and have a function called descendant that
    will return a list that has all the descendants. For example:

Given the rules:

```
parent('Bob', 'Tim').
parent('Joe', 'Bob').
```

The function call:

```
    descendant('Joe', X).
```

should return:

```
        X = ['Bob', 'Tim'].
```

I can get it to return the immediate descendant of 'Joe' but not the full line. Here's what I have.

```
 % Recursive case
  descendant(X,DList) :- parent(X,A), NewDList = [A|DList], 
                         descendant(A, NewDList).
 % Base case, I have a feeling this is wrong.
  descendant(_,[]).
```

This code only seems to return true or false, or just an empty [].

I could use some help on what I might need to look at. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, we'll create a predicate that can finds a single descendant.

```
descendant(X, Y) :- parent(X, Y).
descendant(X, Y) :- parent(X, Z), descendant(Z, Y).
```

We can then use the `findall` predicate to list all descendants:

```
descendants(X, L) :- findall(A, descendant(X, A), L).
```

So, for instance:

```
parent(bob, tim).
parent(joe, bob).
parent(joe, mary).

descendant(X, Y) :- parent(X, Y).
descendant(X, Y) :- parent(X, Z), descendant(Z, Y).

descendants(X, L) :- findall(A, descendant(X, A), L).
```

gives:

```
?- descendants(joe, X).
X = [bob, mary, tim].
```

Comment: Well the problem of having someone say having 6 children, I would want it to list all 6 as descendants. However, the rules given only have people having one child which allows the implementation audrey gave acceptable. But I would like to know how to do that in case it came up later on a test. I tried this one, but all it returns is the direct descendant, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `descendants` (with an s) is being used, rather than `descendant` (which unifies one person with a descendant)?

Comment: Yea, what's happening is it will output X = [bob]
I have to push ; for it to step and put out X = [mary] and so on until it errors out.

Comment: What version of Prolog are you using? I'm using SWI Prolog 5.8.

Answer (score 0):

My Prolog is a bit rusty and I'm loathe to post an answer to such a problem - you won't learn much that way.

I'll just point out that you shouldn't have that assignment statement in there - NewDList = [A|DList] - this is considered bad form in the Prolog style of programming - assignments should only be used where there is not a "pure" logical solution - certainly not the case here.

Cheers,
Craig.

Answer (score 0):

```
parent('Bob', 'Tim').
parent('Joe', 'Bob').

descendant(X,[H|T]) :- parent(X,H), descendant(H, T).
descendant(X,[]) .
```

returns

```
?- descendant('Joe', L).
L = ['Bob', 'Tim'] ;
L = ['Bob'] ;
L = [].
```

actually it is hard to write predicate that will return only `['Bob', 'Tim']` because list `['Bob']` is also valid. if you decide to leave only longest chain it gets too comlicated

if i understood question incorrectly here is one version:

```
desc(X, A) :- parent(X,H), desc(H, A).
desc(X, A) :- X = A.
```

Comment: I don't think this works if somebody has more than one direct descendant, for instance if Joe is also the parent of Mary.

Comment: did you test it? if not please test then critique. i just tested it. i works fine. i you are SURE that it doesn't work at certain data please give a proof

Comment: The example I gave doesn't work -- if I add parent('Joe', 'Mary'), then the descendants of Joe are still listed as Bob and Tim (although Mary is given as a further result when backtracking)

Comment: i just added your rule and result is L = ['Bob', 'Tim'] ;
L = ['Bob'] ;
L = ['Mary'] ;
L = [].
which is expected

Comment: From the question, I would expect the result to be L = ['Bob', 'Tim', 'Mary']